# List control in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to create a simple list of items on a window in OSX.
Coming from C# background I am looking for a corresponding version of a List ,

A simple control in which all items are added in only one column and vertical order and that's pretty much it. I saw NSTableView in the library but it seems to be a more fancy control with multiple columns like a listview in C#,

Is it the one I need to modify the properties to simplify or is there a simpler control for what I need ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSTableView should be fine for what you want. You can change how it is set up, but usually it just lists things in a single row, vertical format. NSTableView may have more options, but if you just don't use them, everything should be fine.

If there is another reason you don't want to use NSTableView let me know.

Good luck.

Comment: No there is no reason not to use it, just wanted to be sure to use the appropriate control,

Comment: Wonderful. That's great! I would definitely use NSTableView. Actually, I wonder if there even is a decent alternative.